# How do I remove the bar from the picture password screen in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, login-screen

I think the bar which comes on the left side of the Windows 8 picture password screen is ugly, I'd like to make it transparent. I want my logon background to be fullscreen. Any tools/hacks to do this yet?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, as there wouldn't be any way to switch to a password, for example.

Also Microsoft has restricted most 3rd-party developer access to parts of the UI and experience they deem critical (e.g. you cannot pin your program to the task bar or Start programmatically). UI changes to core Windows functions are pretty much included in that.

Comment: I meant making the bar transparent. Hope something comes up in the future.

Comment: I still very much doubt so.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Still hoping for a solution..

Answer (score 0):

That bar is required! And, nopes, it is not possible